# How do I undo a close of a tab?

Tags: notifications, menu, recents-screen, samsung-galaxy-mega-2, samsung-galaxy-s-6-edge+

I upgraded from Galaxy Mega to Galaxy S6 Edge +.

There seems to be no undo button. In Galaxy Mega, when I use Chrome, I can undo close tabs. However, in S6E+, each tab opened in chrome is part of the list of running apps as seen when pressing the Recent button on the lower left.

How can I undo a close of of a tab in chrome?

Can I undo a close of an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a workaround that leads to a solution but not a direct solution:

If you have Chrome tabs as separate entities in the Overview (Recent Apps) section, then undoing the closure of a tab is not possible. However, if you open Chrome and tap on the three-dotted menu in the right-hand corner and then tap `Settings` and navigate to `Merge tabs and apps` and move the slider to off then your tabs will appear under a seperate tab switcher inside Chrome (this is, I suspect, how your previous phone handled tabs). When you now close tabs, the option to undo the closure is visible.